# Postgresql and Docker

Tags: docker

We have an application which is splitted in several git repositories:

1. WebApp Git Repository (Django + Postgres + Celery)
2. Workers (Python + Celery)

With that we also need a rabbitmq-server. I was able to successfully dockerize the first WebApp but I had some questions about dockerisation and more specifically about Postgres.

Today we have one database, used by our webbApp. This database is created in Postgres Container using a script we placed in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as specified in [Official Postgres Container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

If tomorrow, I have a second web apps, which need to use a postgres database, do I absolutely need to modify my current postgres container to create the new database ? Is it better to create a new postgres container with this particular database?  And one thing I have difficulties with: the data in my container are not persistent. All data written in postgres container will be destroyed when the container is stopped. What is the docker's compliant solution to keep thoses data persistent ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a data volume to make your data persistent.

```
docker run -v /var/lib/postgresql/data --name dbdata busybox /bin/true
docker run --volume-from dbdata postgresql # and additional parameters
```

To create a new database, you can enter the container by using [nsenter](https://blog.docker.com/tag/nsenter/)

```
# start the shell in a container
ne() {
 pid=$(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' $1)
 env SHELL='/bin/bash' sudo -E nsenter --target $pid \
  --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
}
```

ne my_postgresql_container

(Reference: http://docs.blowb.org/setup-host/docker.html)

You can save the function to your `.bashrc` file if you want to use it more frequently.

Inside there, start postgresql client and run the sql statements to create the database.

Answer (score 0):

there are two schools of thought for your postgres database instances.

- create a single database for all apps, then you can do a single backup and wal log files and replication.
- create a database container for each application. This was each application is responsible for its database. I prefer this approach because there doesn't have to be any cooperation between applications.

As far as where to put the data, it can:

- go in the postgres container.
- go in a data only container, and mount it with --volumes-from from the postgres container. The data only container can use the same image as the postgres container.
- go on the host itself, and the data is mounted from the host.  This is probably the safest option because the data isn't connected to the container.

This is a tricky problem, especially when you start composing with docker-compose, fleet, swarm, kubernetes, etc..  You don't want your database data to disappear.

As long as you  backup your database periodically, you have an 'off container' worst case recovery option.  If you in addition copy the transaction logs to another host, then you can recover using a backup + transaction logs to almost a current edition.  Or, you can use a replication database and pipe your data to another container so if your primary goes down you have it in a backup container.

To me, if the database is big and central, it would make sense to manage that database *outside* docker and point to it with the containers that use it, but that is just my opinion :-)